# How to determine numeric equivalent of Tiny, Small, etc. image sizes for Graphics?

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to find the numeric equivalents of `Tiny`, `Small`, `Medium`, and `Large` for for `ImageSize`?  In other words, what are the integers `t`, `s`, `m`, and `l` such that, for `Graphics` objects, the directives

```
ImageSize -> t
ImageSize -> s
ImageSize -> m
ImageSize -> l
```

are equivalent, respectively, to the directives

```
ImageSize -> Tiny
ImageSize -> Small
ImageSize -> Medium
ImageSize -> Large
```

?

Comment: I think they produce the same result for all graphics but I'm not sure, but if that's the case: `imgs = Graphics[Rectangle[{1, 1}], ImageSize -> #] & /@ {Tiny, Small, 
   Medium, Large}` and then `ImageDimensions /@ imgs`

Comment: Depends on a case: `Slider[.5, ImageSize -> Tiny] // Rasterize // ImageDimensions`

Comment: Good point @Vitaliy, I assumed we're talking about `Graphics`.  kjo, can you update your question and specify whether you're talking only about graphics or all situations?

Comment: @Szabolcs: done (yes, I was referring to `Graphics` only)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can obtain the sizes like this:

```
In[1]:= Rasterize[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> #], "RasterSize"] & /@ {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}

Out[1]= {{100, 100}, {180, 180}, {360, 359}, {576, 575}}
```

It is the horizontal size that is relevant.  The vertical size will depend on the aspect ratio.  Thus `ImageSize -> Medium` corresponds to `ImageSize -> 360`.

**A warning:** In some cases `Tiny`, `Small`, etc. do not directly correspond to numerical values, and their effect depends on the context.   I do not know if this is the case for `ImageSize` or not (I could imagine it might depend on the screen DPI setting, but then it might not.)  I'm just warning you.  (An example where this happens is `Arrowheads`, where using numerical values causes the arrow to scale with the graphic, while using e.g. `Large` makes the arrow size independent of the image size.)

---

Edit by István:

Below is a comprehensive list of possible `ImageSize` specifications for various objects, with default settings:

```
spec = {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large, All, None, Full, 
        Automatic, {Large, Automatic}, {{Tiny}, {Medium}},
        100, {100, 100}, Scaled@.6};

Panel@TableForm[{
   Rasterize[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> #], "RasterSize"] & /@ spec,
   Rasterize[Graphics3D[{}, ImageSize -> #], "RasterSize"] & /@ spec,
   Rasterize[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> #], "RasterSize"] & /@ spec,
   Rasterize[Slider[x, {0, 1}, ImageSize -> #], "RasterSize"] & /@ spec,
   Rasterize[Quiet@Pane["x", ImageSize -> #], "RasterSize"] & /@ spec
   } // Transpose, 
 TableHeadings -> {spec, {Graphics, Graphics3D, Plot, Slider, Pane}}, 
 TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: This I steal for the [`PlotExplorer`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7144/89)... Very handy, and was delivered at the perfect time, thanks!

Comment: You're assuming the graphic is square...

Comment: @Brett It is only because an empty `Graphics` is by default assumed to be square by _Mathematica_.

Comment: @Brett I should have mentioned that it's the horizontal size that matters.  I'll update the answer.