# Interpolating or "absolutising" symbolic sizes for graphic primitives?

Tags: graphics

I often face the problem that none of the usual symbolic constants `Tiny`, `Small`, `Medium`, or `Large` or similar works quite well. For instance I would like something between `Medium` and `Large`, or just a tiny bit more than `Large`. I then need to resort to absolute sizes which costs time and is somewhat frustrating as the only way I know is trial and error and my first shot is usually terribly off (not to mention it might be daunting when the graphics is complicated). What's also bad, when the range of the plot later changes (beyond my control), the absolute sizes need to be readjusted.

Is it possible to perhaps find what values `Medium` and `Large` evaluate to, say for `PointSize`, and use some arithmetic on those?

**EDIT**: The [suggested duplicate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/how-to-determine-numeric-equivalent-of-tiny-small-etc-image-sizes-for-graphic) deals with the size of the `Graphics` as a whole. I would primarily be interested in the meaning of these tokens for scaling of graphic primitives, like the values of `PointSize` (as originally mentioned but probably only too subtly), font size within a `Style`, `Thickness`, `Arrowheads`, and similar. Any subset of the mentioned, should the generic form make the question too broad. The method proposed in the [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/how-to-determine-numeric-equivalent-of-tiny-small-etc-image-sizes-for-graphic) can not be adapted to this case in any straightforward way.

Comment: related: [How to determine numeric equivalent of Tiny, Small, etc. image sizes for Graphics?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31726/5478)

Comment: I found it much better to use `Scaled` sizes for everything instead of either the symbolic constants or explicit absolute sizes. Those just work better when scaling the graphic up or down, retaining the relative shape and position.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to use `Rasterize` to approximate the size of things.  I show it for points (as asked for in the OP) and lines.  Points are not easy to get right.  And `Rasterize` jumps from one rasterized size to the next as `s` increases in `PointSize[s]` (as well as `Thickness[s]`), so in the numbers below should be looked at as pretty close to correct.  The floating-point estimates were rationalized, and the rationalizations checked.  Both give the same sizes as `{Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}`.

```
(* rasterizer *)
rGraphics[size_, elem_][s_] := ColorConvert[
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[{White,
      size@s, elem},
     PlotRange -> 1/2],
    Background -> Black,
    RasterSize -> 2000],
   "Grayscale"];
```

Points:

```
(* Points *)
rPoint = rGraphics[PointSize, Point[{0, 0}]];

pointsizes = Table[
  rPoint[s] // ImageData // Sqrt[Total[#, 2]/Times @@ Dimensions[#]] &,
  {s, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}]
(*  {0.003, 0.00490818, 0.0110642, 0.0172208}  *)

{1.`, 1.1319, 1.12977, 1.129125} pointsizes
(*  {0.003, 0.00555556, 0.0125, 0.0194444}  *)

test = Table[
  rPoint[s] // ImageData // Sqrt[Total[#, 2]/Times @@ Dimensions[#]] &,
  {s, {1.`, 1.1319, 1.12977, 1.129125} pointsizes}]
(*  {0.003, 0.00490818, 0.0110642, 0.0172208}  *)

(* rationalized *)
test = Table[
  rPoint[s] // ImageData // Sqrt[Total[#, 2]/Times @@ Dimensions[#]] &,
  {s, {3/1000, 1/180, 1/80, 7/360}}]
(*  {0.003, 0.00490818, 0.0110642, 0.0172208}  *)

pointsizes/test
(*  {1., 1., 1., 1.}  *)
```

Lines:

```
(* Lines *)
rLine = rGraphics[Thickness, Line[{{-1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0}}]];

thicknesses = Table[
  rLine[s] // ImageData // Total[#, 2]/Times @@ Dimensions[#] &,
  {s, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}]
(*  {0.000556502, 0.00138791, 0.00278039, 0.00555686}  *)

test = Table[
  rLine[s] // ImageData // Total[#, 2]/Times @@ Dimensions[#] &,
  {s, thicknesses}]
(*  {0.000556502, 0.00138791, 0.00278039, 0.00555686}  *)

(* rationalized *)
test = Table[
  rLine[s] // ImageData // Total[#, 2]/Times @@ Dimensions[#] &,
  {s, {1/1800, 1/720, 1/360, 1/180}}]
(*  {0.000556502, 0.00138791, 0.00278039, 0.00555686}  *)

thicknesses/test
(*  {1.`, 1.`, 1.`, 1.`}   *)
```

Summary:

[image]