# Is there any simple way to zoom/magnify a selected portion of a plot (like gnuplot or xmgrace)?

Tags: plotting

Is there any simple way to zoom a particular portion of a plot (similar to what you can do with gnuplot or xmgrace using the magnifier and selecting a region)?

Usually I do it by varying the `PlotRange[]` manually or by putting the `PlotRange[]` under `Manipulate[]`, but that is not very convenient option for heavy plotting (which involve complicated functions or large data). Is there anything like a magnifier tool or something similar?

Comment: Take a look at [how to manipulate 2D plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7142/5478)

Comment: For just simple zooming, click on plot so you see frame, ctrl-click on frame marker and drag to narrow, release control and drag frame to desired size...