# Interactive Mandelbrot Zoomer?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fractals

I want to combine Manipulate with ManbelbrotSetPlot just to get Mathematica to give me a quick and dirty Mandelbrot Zoomer. I want to be able to single/double click on a section, and have it zoom in on that section. All I've been able to get is an adjustable viewing window, but that's really not satisfactory. I imagine a Locator might do the trick, but I'm unsure how to get it to work. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Interesting question, sadly, with no effort shown on your side it will be hard to get enough attention to it

Comment: What do you suggest I try?

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48444/how-do-i-built-a-zoomable-koch-curve) is how to zoom in on a Koch curve, it can probably be adapted. There are several other questions about zooming as well that you might take a look at.

Comment: @Pickett That's really interesting. I'm going to have to spend quite some time to figure out how it works.

Comment: There is also [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FiveFamousFractals/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way to zoom around is using Manipulate. Here we use a 2D slider to set the position and a regular slider to set the zoom. It scrolls more evenly if you hold down the option key as you move the sliders.

```
Manipulate[b = -Log[a]; 
 MandelbrotSetPlot[{u[[1]] + u[[2]] I - b - b I, u[[1]] + u[[2]] I + b + b I}, 
  MaxIterations -> 200], {{a, 0.50, "zoom"}, 0, 0.999}, {u, {-2, -1.3}, {0.6, 1.3}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Quick&Dirty:

```
pt = {0, 0};    
full = MandelbrotSetPlot[];
r = 0.2;

Column[{
  Row[{"Zoom: ", Slider[Dynamic[r], {0.01, 1}]}],
  Row[
   {
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
     Dynamic[Show[full, 
       Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Transparent, 
         Rectangle[pt + r, pt - r]}], ImageSize -> Scaled[.45]]]],
    Dynamic[
     MandelbrotSetPlot[{pt + r, pt - r}.{1, I}, 
      ImageSize -> Scaled[.45]], TrackedSymbols :> {pt, r}]
    }]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really nice, unfortunately it is aborting in my copy of Mathematica 10 with the error Set::write: "Tag Span in {-0.7,0.4};;full is Protected."

Comment: Ok, now it's working.

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a less quick and dirty version that includes a few more features. To zoom in, you simply click and drag to select a rectangle. Generally, you've got to hit the `Generate` button to produce the next picture. If you just click on the image, then a picture of the corresponding Julia set will be printed to the notebook, together with the command to generate it.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
(* Adjust as desired *)
imageSize = 800;
defaultBailout = 100;
bailoutOptions = {50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000};
defaultResolution = 400;
resolutionOptions = {400, 800, 1600};
defaultColorScheme = "StarryNightColors"
colorSchemes = ColorData["Gradients"];

(* Initial settings *)
pt = {0, 0}; pt1 = {-2, -1.3}; pt2 = {0.6, 1.3};
plotRange = {{-2, 0.6}, {-1.3, 1.3}};

Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{},
  toShow = Show[{mandelbrotPic, Graphics[{
       Thickness[0.005], Opacity[0.5], Gray,
       Dynamic@Line[{pt1, {pt1[[1]], pt2[[2]]}, pt2,
          {pt2[[1]], pt1[[2]]}, pt1}]
       }]}, FrameTicks -> False, PlotRange -> Dynamic@plotRange];
  Deploy[If[showBounds === True,
    Labeled[
     EventHandler[toShow,
      {"MouseClicked" :> With[{cmd = 
       Hold[JuliaSetPlot[#]]&[{1, I}.MousePosition["Graphics"]]},
       CellPrint[{ExpressionCell[Defer @@ cmd, "Input"], 
                  ExpressionCell[ReleaseHold[cmd], "Output"]}]],
       "MouseDown" :> (pt2 = pt1 = pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
       "MouseDragged" :> (pt2 = pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
       "MouseUp" :> (pt2 = pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])}],
     {pt1, pt2}],
    EventHandler[toShow,
     {"MouseClicked" :> With[{cmd = 
       Hold[JuliaSetPlot[#]]&[{1, I}.MousePosition["Graphics"]]},
       CellPrint[{ExpressionCell[Defer @@ cmd, "Input"], 
                  ExpressionCell[ReleaseHold[cmd], "Output"]}]],
      "MouseDown" :> (pt2 = pt1 = pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
      "MouseDragged" :> (pt2 = pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]),
      "MouseUp" :> (pt2 = pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])}]]]],
 Row[{
   Button["Generate",
    plotRange = {{pt1[[1]], pt2[[1]]}, {pt1[[2]], pt2[[2]]}};
    mandelbrotPic = 
     MandelbrotSetPlot[{pt1[[1]] + pt1[[2]]*I, 
       pt2[[1]] + pt2[[2]]*I},
      MaxIterations -> bail, ImageResolution -> resolution, 
      ImageSize -> imageSize,
      ColorFunction -> colorScheme],
    Method -> "Queued"
    ],
   Button["Reset",
    bail = defaultBailout; 
    resolution = defaultResolution;
    colorScheme = defaultColorScheme;
    plotRange = {{-2, 0.6}, {-1.3, 1.3}};
    mandelbrotPic = MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.0 - 1.3 I, 0.6 + 1.3 I},
      MaxIterations -> bail, ImageResolution -> resolution, 
      ImageSize -> imageSize,
      ColorFunction -> colorScheme];
    pt = {0, 0}; pt1 = {-2, -1.3}; pt2 = {0.6, 1.3};]}],
 {{bail, defaultBailout, "Bailout"}, bailoutOptions, 
  ControlType -> SetterBar}, 
 {{resolution, defaultResolution, "Resolution"}, resolutionOptions},
 {{colorScheme, defaultColorScheme, "Color Scheme"}, colorSchemes},
 {{showBounds, False, "Show PlotRange"}, {True, False}},
 Initialization :> (
   pt = {0, 0}; pt1 = {-2, -1.3}; pt2 = {0.6, 1.3};
   plotRange = {{-2, 0.6}, {-1.3, 1.3}};
   mandelbrotPic = MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.0 - 1.3 I, 0.6 + 1.3 I},
     MaxIterations -> bail, ImageResolution -> resolution, 
     ImageSize -> imageSize,
     ColorFunction -> colorScheme];)
 ]
```

Comment: This is very nice to play with!  Something that annoys me about `MandelbrotSetPlot` is that increasing the `MaxIterations` will make some interesting features very faint, and will only highlight the inner edges.  However, not increasing `MaxIterations` will not reveal those interesting features.  Perhaps something like this can be a fix: `Colorize[HistogramTransform@
  Image@First@
    MandelbrotSetPlot[{-0.924 + 0.33 I, -0.913 + 0.316 I}, 
     MaxIterations -> 1000, ImageResolution -> 1000, 
     ColorFunction -> GrayLevel], ColorFunction -> "BeachColors"]`

Comment: Of course, this has its own issues too.  Sometimes just raising the image to a power less than 1 is better. 11.1 supports direct image arithmetic.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! Your complaint is a consequence of the way that iteration counts behave and the fact that those counts are mapped linearly to the colors. One solution is to manipulate those counts inside the `ColorFunction`. Compare `ColorFunction -> "BeachColors"` to `ColorFunction ->  If[#3 == 1, Black, ColorData["BeachColors"][#3^(0.4)]] &)`, for example. I guess that's essentially what you're doing when you raise the image to a power, though I suspect you have finer control when working with the `ColorFunction`. It is a little slower, though.