# how to use a ready function in your code for panning and zooming on 2D plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics

As I said before for the time being, I don't want to use `Mathematica` as a programming tool. I'm just using it as a calculater to compute integrals, solve equations, etc because of its support of symbolic math.
So my question is not about [adding zooming and panning capability to your code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=zoom)

As you know in 3D graphics (as far as I know graphics that are created by Plot3D function) we can use:

- Click + Drag ---> Rotate
- Alt + Click + Drag ---> Zoom in and out
- Shift+Click+Drag ---> Pan

but for 2D graphics (as far as I know graphics that are created by Plot function) we don't have such capability.

I searched a bit on the net and in this site and found out that there are no built in plot manipulating interface in mathematica and I should use [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7144/30689) to be able to pan and zoom on 2D plots that I have created in notebook.
**But I don't know how to use a certain piece of code and call a function in mathematica.** I'm just starting to learn, so please pardon me if it's so trivial.

For example suppose that I have created this plot and now I want to be able to pan and zoom on it. **What should I do?**

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[PDF[VonMisesDistribution[μ, κ], x], {x, -Pi + μ, 
   Pi + μ}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 20}}], {{μ, 0}, -5, 
  5}, {{κ, 5}, 0, 1000}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how to use a certain piece of code"? Are you talking about a specific piece of code or code in general? I assume by now you should have figured out how to run code. As to the specific question at the bottom of the post: just change the numbers in the x range to pan and the numbers in the PlotRange option to zoom. You can make those numbers parameters in the Manipulate as well.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries changing the numbers of `PlotRange` is one way. But I want to know if there is any built-in way as in **Plot3D**, some GUI interface that enables you to pan. The code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-manipulate-2d-plots/7144#7144) seems to be able to add this GUI to a 2D graphic. about the sentence `I don't know how to use a certain piece of code and call a function in mathematica.`: My purpose is that for example in C++ we have object oriented programming. We use 3rd party libraries and are not aware of their implementation. We are just

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries familiar with the interface of the function in the library. We call the functions in our code, pass parameters to them and get the output and use in our code. or in matlab if I want to use this [ready function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27172-envi-file-reader-writer) in my code, I just put the M-file of it in the same directory that my code is running. And I just call the functions in my code. My purpose is if we consider [this code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-manipulate-2d-plots/7144#7144) a ready package, how should

Comment: I use that ready functions in my code?

Comment: Just run the PlotExplorer code in that answer and you can use the PlotExplorer function as shown as in the examples in the post. The libraries you are looking for are called *packages* in Mathematica. You can read about them [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries should add the implementation of the function to the top of my note book or somewhere else?

Comment: That doesn't really matter as long as you run that definition before you start using the function.

Comment: @dionys I should flag the question and request moderators to mark it as duplicate?

Comment: @dionys I think I have also chosen the wrong title. My question was actually how to use that [ready piece of code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-manipulate-2d-plots/7144#7144) in my work as you see in the comments? maybe it's better to change the title to **how to use a ready function in your code for panning and zooming on 2D plots**?

Comment: @sepideh It's up to you, but if I were you I would probably just edit out anything that isn't relevant for future readers and flag it as a duplicate question. You get some credit for helpful flags as well (in the form of meaningless internet points).

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Pane[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}],
  ImageSize -> {300, 200},
  Scrollbars -> True,
  ScrollPosition -> {a, b}],
 {a, 10, 200},
 {b, 10, 200}]
```

Comment: Very nice.  I wasn't aware of the `Srollbars` option.  From this I can see that a "zoom" can also be added: `Manipulate[
 Pane[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> zoom {600, 400}], 
  ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Scrollbars -> True], {{zoom, 1, "Zoom"}, 
  0.1, 10}]`

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7144/30689) by @IstvánZachar that you linked seems to do all that you want and more:

```
Attributes[PlotExplorer] = {HoldFirst};
PlotExplorer[defPlot_] := 
  DynamicModule[{held, head, plot, range, zoomRange, defRange, 
    defSize, defEpilog, size, pt1, pt2, spt1, dist, rect = {}, 
    dragged = False, overButton = False, pushedButton = False, 
    overHor = False, overVer = False, activeHor = False, 
    activeVer = False, xPos = .5, yPos = .5, minDistance = 0.1, 
    sliderRatio = 0.05, panFactor = 10, reset, distance, slider, 
    replot, coord = None}, held = Hold@defPlot;
   head = Part[held, 1, 0];
   plot = defPlot;
   {defEpilog, defRange} = {Epilog, PlotRange} /. 
     Quiet@AbsoluteOptions@plot;
   defEpilog = defEpilog /. Epilog -> {};
   size = defSize = Rasterize[plot, "RasterSize"];
   range = zoomRange = defRange;
   Deploy@
    EventHandler[
     Dynamic[MouseAppearance[
       Show[plot, PlotRange -> Dynamic@range, 
        Epilog -> {defEpilog,(*Original epilog*)(*Replot button*)
          EventHandler[
           Inset[Graphics[{Black, 
              Dynamic@
               Opacity@If[overButton, If[pushedButton, .2, .1], 0], 
              Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, RoundingRadius -> Offset@5], 
              Black, Dynamic@
               Opacity@If[overButton, If[pushedButton, .9, .7], 0], 
              Text["Replot", Center]}, ImageSize -> 50, 
             AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
             BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], Scaled@{1, 1},
             Scaled@{1, 1}], {"MouseEntered" :> (overButton = True), 
            "MouseExited" :> (overButton = False), 
            "MouseDown" :> (pushedButton = True), 
            "MouseUp" :> (pushedButton = False; 
              replot@plot)}],(*Zoom rectangle*)
          FaceForm@{Blue, Opacity@.1}, 
          EdgeForm@{Thin, Dotted, Opacity@.5}, 
          Dynamic@rect,(*Range sliders*)
          Inset[slider[Dynamic@xPos, Dynamic@overHor, 
            Dynamic@activeHor, size, True], Scaled@{.5, 0}, 
           Scaled@{.5, 0}], 
          Inset[slider[Dynamic@yPos, Dynamic@overVer, 
            Dynamic@activeVer, size, False], Scaled@{0, .5}, 
           Scaled@{0, .5}]}],(*cursor*)
       Which[dragged, "FrameRisingResize", CurrentValue@"AltKey", 
        Graphics[{Antialiasing -> False, Line@{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 
          Line@{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}, 
          Dynamic@Text[
            Style[coord, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 8], {0, 
             0}, {-1.1, -1}]}, ImageSize -> 160, ImagePadding -> 0, 
         AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}*8], 
        CurrentValue@"ControlKey" && ! overHor && ! overVer, 
        "ZoomView", CurrentValue@"ShiftKey" && ! overHor && ! overVer,
         "DragGraphics", 
        CurrentValue@"ShiftKey" && (overHor || overVer), "LinkHand", 
        True, Automatic]], 
      TrackedSymbols :> {dragged, 
        plot}], {"MouseMoved" :> (coord = MousePosition@"Graphics"), 
      "MouseClicked" :> 
       If[! overButton && CurrentValue@"MouseClickCount" == 2, 
        reset[]], 
      "MouseDown" :> 
       If[(! overHor || ! overVer), pt1 = MousePosition@"Graphics";
        spt1 = MousePosition@"GraphicsScaled"], 
      "MouseDragged" :> 
       If[(! overHor && ! overVer || dragged) && ! overButton && ! 
          pushedButton && ! activeVer && ! activeHor, dragged = True;
        Which[CurrentValue@"ControlKey", 
         dist = Last@MousePosition@"GraphicsScaled" - Last@spt1;
         range = 
          zoomRange*10^
            dist,(*"GraphicsScaled" is required below as "Graphics" \
would give jumpy results as the plot range is constantly modified.*)
         CurrentValue@"ShiftKey", 
         pt2 = MapThread[
            Rescale, {MousePosition@
              "GraphicsScaled", {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, zoomRange}] - pt1;
         range = zoomRange - pt2, True, pt2 = MousePosition@"Graphics";
         rect = If[pt2 === None, {}, Rectangle[pt1, pt2]]]], 
      "MouseUp" :> (If[! CurrentValue@"ShiftKey" && ! 
           CurrentValue@"ControlKey" && dragged && 
          distance[pt1, pt2, zoomRange] > minDistance, rect = {};
         range = Transpose@Sort@{pt1, pt2};]; zoomRange = range;
        dragged = False)}, PassEventsDown -> True, 
     PassEventsUp -> True], 
   Initialization :> (slider[Dynamic[pos_], Dynamic[over_], 
       Dynamic[active_], size_, hor_] := 
      EventHandler[
       Dynamic[LocatorPane[
         If[hor, Dynamic[{pos, .5}, (pos = Clip[First@#, {0, 1}];
             
             range[[1]] = 
              If[CurrentValue@"ShiftKey", 
               
               First@zoomRange + (pos - .5)*
                 Abs[Subtract @@ First@zoomRange]*panFactor, 
               First@zoomRange*10^((pos - .5)*2)]) &], 
          Dynamic[{.5, pos}, (pos = Clip[Last@#, {0, 1}];
             
             range[[2]] = 
              If[CurrentValue@"ShiftKey", 
               Last@zoomRange + (pos - .5)*
                 Abs[Subtract @@ Last@zoomRange]*panFactor, 
               Last@zoomRange*10^((pos - .5)*2)]) &]],(*Locator below \
is required inside Graphics as LocatorPane inside Inset looses the \
crosshair image.*)
         Graphics[{Black, 
           Opacity@If[(over || active) && ! dragged, .1, 0], 
           Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, RoundingRadius -> Offset@5], 
           Opacity@1, 
           Locator[Dynamic@If[hor, {pos, .5}, {.5, pos}], 
            Appearance -> 
             If[(over || active) && ! dragged, Automatic, None]]}, 
          ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
          ImageSize -> 
           If[hor, #*{1, 0} + {0, 20} &, #*{0, 1} + {20, 0} &]@size, 
          AspectRatio -> 
           If[hor, 1/sliderRatio/First@size, sliderRatio*Last@size]], 
         Enabled -> (over || active), Appearance -> None, 
         FrameMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False], 
        TrackedSymbols :> {pos, over, active, 
          dragged}], {"MouseDown" :> (active = True), 
        "MouseUp" :> (active = False), 
        "MouseEntered" :> (over = ! 
            If[hor, activeVer, 
             activeHor]),(*The value of `active` must be public so \
that one slider can check whether the other is dragged,
        not to pop up if the other locator is moved over this \
slider's area.*)"MouseExited" :> (over = False)}, 
       PassEventsDown -> True];
     replot[p_] := 
      Module[{temp}, 
       Switch[head, Plot, 
        temp = ReplacePart[
          held, {{1, 2} -> {held[[1, 2, 1]], range[[1, 1]], 
             range[[1, 2]]}}];
        (*Replace plot range or insert if nonexistent*)
        plot = ReleaseHold@
          If[MemberQ[temp, PlotRange, Infinity], 
           temp /. {_[PlotRange, _] -> (PlotRange -> range)}, 
           Insert[temp, PlotRange -> range, {1, -1}]], 
        DensityPlot | ContourPlot | RegionPlot | StreamPlot | 
         StreamDensityPlot | VectorPlot | VectorDensityPlot | 
         LineIntegralConvolutionPlot, 
        temp = ReplacePart[
          held, {{1, 2} -> {held[[1, 2, 1]], range[[1, 1]], 
             range[[1, 2]]}, {1, 3} -> {held[[1, 3, 1]], 
             range[[2, 1]], range[[2, 2]]}}];
        plot = 
         ReleaseHold@
          If[MemberQ[temp, PlotRange, Infinity], 
           temp /. {_[PlotRange, _] -> (PlotRange -> range)}, 
           Insert[temp, PlotRange -> range, {1, -1}]];, _, Null]];
     reset[] := (range = zoomRange = defRange; xPos = yPos = .5);
     (*Quiet suppresses error message when Rescale[y,{x,
     x}] where y\[NotEqual]x.EuclideanDistance then defaults to \
Infinity which is fine.*)
     distance[p1_, p2_, {r1_, r2_}] := 
      Quiet[N@EuclideanDistance[Rescale[p1, r1], Rescale[p2, r2]]];)];
```

Here is how you can run it on your plot:

```
dist1 /: PDF[dist1[a_, b_], x_] := Exp[b Cos[x - a]]/(2 \[Pi] BesselI[0, b])

PlotExplorer[Plot[PDF[dist1[0, 5], x], {x, -\[Pi] + 0, \[Pi] + 0}]]
```

---

## How to use a certain piece of code and call a function

You don't need to learn all the intricacies of *Mathematica* all at once to use it, but you'll be confused and frustrated by many of the exact things that make *Mathematica* such an excellent tool if you don't spend a little time getting the basics down:

- [making function definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html)
- [going further with functions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CEoQFjAHahUKEwiSrLykn_vHAhUhz3IKHV4gD0A&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.luc.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fdslavsk%2Fcourses%2Fphys301%2Fclassnotes%2FmMoreonMathematica.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFtVq4XtdvkMsRxpW3yihgSIwIHLA&cad=rja)
- [working with variables and functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithVariablesAndFunctions.html)

Comment: Would this thread then rather be a duplicate of the linked one?

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, that is my opinion.

Comment: @dionys I did what you said and flagged it as duplicate of that question after changing the title