# `CandlestickChart` how to display a separate x-axis tick for every single second?

Tags: plotting, charts, finance, financialdata

I use [`CandlestickChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CandlestickChart.html) to display some price data. The data is only 30 seconds long and contains one candle per second. I'd like the chart to display a separate tick on the x-axis for every single second. I tried:

```
CandlestickChart[data, TargetUnits -> {"Seconds", "Dollars"}]
```

> [image]

Unfortunately, as you can see the chart still shows just vague regions for minutes on the x-axis. Which syntax can I use to make it show `year-month-day-hour-minute-second` for each candle?

PS: The data is in the following format for each candle:

```
data = {
           ... ,
           {{year,month,day,hour,minute,second},{open, high,low,close,volume}},
           ...
        }
```

EDIT:

Example data (not the same as in picture above):

```
data = { {{2022,9,15,15,43,50},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,51},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,52},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,53},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,54},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,55},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,56},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,57},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,58},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,43,59},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,44,00},{5, 6,4,5,1}},
         {{2022,9,15,15,44,01},{5, 6,4,5,1}} };
```

I imagine if the plot works for this data, it will work for my actual data as well.

Comment: Edit your question to include some data.

Comment: @BobHanlon I've added some generated example data.

Comment: This doesn't look trivial as methods using with ChartLabel and FrameTicks do not work. (It seems CandlestickChart has an override on the x-axis. eg: CandlestickChart[
 dataObjects,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks ->
  {
   {
    {4.5, 5.5}, None
    },
   {
    {{2022, 9, 15, 15, 43, 52}, {2022, 9, 15, 15, 43, 58}}, None
    }
   },
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12]
 ] does not highlight the x-axis.) Could you use another chart type or is CandlestickChart a must ?

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability I was hoping to plot a candlestick chart... maybe there is a way to mcGyver together "candlesticks" into a regular Plot? Not sure...

Comment: @Kagaratsch you might get inspiration here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139653/60568